# Where do we need to use static factory method in Spring?

Tags: spring

**context.xml**

```xml
<!-- the factory bean, which contains a method called createInstance() -->
<bean id="serviceLocator" class="examples.DefaultServiceLocator">
<!-- inject any dependencies required by this locator bean -->
</bean>
<!-- the bean to be created via the factory bean -->
<bean id="clientService"
factory-bean="serviceLocator"
factory-method="createClientServiceInstance"/>
```

**DefaultServiceLocator.java**

```java
public class DefaultServiceLocator {
    private static ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
    private DefaultServiceLocator() {}
    public ClientService createClientServiceInstance() {
    return clientService;
  }
}
```

Here we can use normal bean creation. So where we prefer this kind of Static factory Method and where normal bean creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use a factory method when a constructor can't do the job:

- if you need to instantiate one class or another based on some argument, system property or environment variable
- if the class to instantiate doesn't even provide a constructor but is only obtainable by using a factory method. See for example [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29).
- if the object to create must be configured by calling various initialization methods or setters after being constructed.

Note that modern Spring applications shouldn't use XML to create such beans. They should use a Configuration class, containing @Bean annotated methods creating beans.

Comment: Thanks for clearing all my doubts regarding Static Factory method in spring.